# Can I draw lines on top of an "gif" image using the <canvas> function?

Tags: html, canvas

I'm having difficulty drawing lines on top of an uploaded "map.gif" image.

Basically I've upload a small outline map and use the "area" function to create defined areas (cities, roads, etc).  When I click on a city a snall pop up gets displayed with the word "hey, you've just click on Dallas" (or where ever). All that works just fine.

My problem is that my map is actually just a blank outline with no actual cities or roads drawn on it.

Therefore I tried using the "canvas" function to draw the cities (circles) and roads (lines).

The only problem is that they appear below the map rather than on top of it.

Any ideas as to how I can get the lines to appear on the map?

Many thanks,

Pete

Comment: Can you link to a live example? A number of different ways to do this come to mind, but some context would be cool.

Answer (score 1):

You might just have to try playing with the CSS z-index values of the image and canvas.
Do make sure you set the canvas to be transparent.

An other possibility is to replace the image with the canvas (or just load the image in the canvas to begin with).
For some hints on how to use images with canvas take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images).

Answer (score 0):

I would load the gif directly in the canvas memory, and then do all the rest inside the canvas itself.

The gif is not animated, right?

Some reference about loading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images